# Javascript forEach return value interpolated into string

Tags: javascript, json, object, foreach

```
stack_html += "<div class='co-stack-layer-title'>Application and Data" +
                        "<div class='row'>" +
                          response['Application and Data'].forEach(generateStackItem) + 
                        "</div>" +
                      "</div>";
stack_html += "<div class='co-stack-layer-title'>Business Tools" +
                        "<div class='row'>" +
                          response['Business Tools'].forEach(generateStackItem) + 
                        "</div>" +
                      "</div>";
stack_html += "<div class='co-stack-layer-title'>DevOps" +
                        "<div class='row'>" +
                          response['DevOps'].forEach(generateStackItem) + 
                        "</div>" +
                      "</div>";
stack_html += "<div class='co-stack-layer-title'>Utilities" +
                        "<div class='row'>" +
                          response['Utilities'].forEach(generateStackItem) + 
                        "</div>" +
                      "</div>";

function generateStackItem(element, index, array) {
    var stack_item_html = "";
    stack_item_html += "<div class='co-service'>" +
                     "<a href='" + element['canonical_url'] + "' class='each-service hint hint--top' data-hint='" + element['name'] + "' data-align='left'>" +
                       "<img src='" + element['image_url'] + "'>" +
                     "</a>" +
                   "</div>";

    console.log(stack_item_html);
    return stack_item_html;                       
}
```

---

I'm trying to use a `forEach` iteration on a javascript object, and it seems I cannot interpolate the return value into the string addition.

```
<div class='co-stack-layer-title'>Application and Data<div class='row'>undefined</div></div><div class='co-stack-layer-title'>Business Tools<div class='row'>undefined</div></div><div class='co-stack-layer-title'>DevOps<div class='row'>undefined</div></div><div class='co-stack-layer-title'>Utilities<div class='row'>undefined</div></div>
```

Comment: How does the response you are using look like? What do you want to do with generateStackItem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) returns `undefined`. Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)+`join`.

```
"abc" + response['Utilities'].map(generateStackItem).join("") + "def";
```

Comment: map + join = [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), with a little tweaking to the callback.

Comment: map + join != reduce. In the case of a join you can properly glue your pieces together, with a reduce that's harder to do. It doesn't really matter here though.

Answer (score 0):

When your array is empty, the `forEach` function will return `undefined`, e.g.you will get an `undefined` when you call `forEach` like this `[].forEach(generateStackItem)`, so check if your `response['Application and Data']` is an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

From [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Description)

> forEach() executes the callback function once for each array element;
> unlike map() or reduce() it always returns the value undefined and is
> not chainable. The typical use case is to execute side effects at the
> end of a chain.

It's common mistake to use return inside forEach in this way but it will not work. You may want to look at `map`